# How do you use inline-haml for dyanmic content?

Tags: html, haml, erb

The intent is to do what you think this would achieve, except doing so without using erb.

= link_to 'text', some_path, id: <%= @name %>

What is the most elegant way to do somethign like this in haml? Should you just use haml and erb in a `*.haml.erb` file?

Comment: Are you just looking for `= link_to 'text", some_path, id: @name`?

Comment: Yeah that's it. Everything is already allowed as ruby.

Comment: @ahnbizcad are you still having an issue? If not, please check out the answer(s) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@matt pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858357/how-do-you-use-inline-haml-for-dyanmic-content/29636048#comment38615830_24858357), the best way to "convert" that line to strictly haml is the following

```
= link_to 'text', some_path, id: @name
```

Please note, you should use either `'text'` or `"text"`, and not mix the quotes (like you did in your question). And, if needed, convert `@name` to an int or a string. If it is an object with several attributes, it will print the object/relation ID for ActiveRecord, so specify an attribute (`@name.first_name`)

I also suggest that you stick strictly with *either* haml or erb. It makes life easier when comparing multiple views as once (making sure all index pages look the same). Haml is also very powerful, while being easy on the eyes.

Comment: @ahnbizcad Thank you for accepting the answer. If it helps, please upvote as well.